# Landsat 5 and poor indexing process, on Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-5

I'm trying to map some indexes (NDBI, SAVI, and IBI) using Landsat-5 imagery on Google Earth Engine (GEE). However, my experiment error, I don't know how to solve this problem. Is there any solution to this problem?

Here's my GEE script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd1b217f852604520dfdad23f485efe0

or

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

// This function clips images to the AOI feature collection
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(aoi);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2003-12-31').map(clipToCol)
                  .map(cloudMaskL457)
                  .filterBounds(aoi);


print(dataset)

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.setCenter(105.5, -5.9, 8);
Map.addLayer(dataset.median(), visParams);

//SAVI:Soil-Adjusted Vegetation Index
var savi = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.select().addBands(image.expression(
                        '1.5 * (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + 5000)', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B4'),
                        'RED': image.select('B3')
                    }).float()).rename('SAVI')});
print(savi)

//NDBI:Normalized Normalized Difference Built-Up Index
var ndbi = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.select().addBands(image.expression(
                        '(SWIR - NIR) / (SWIR + NIR)', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B4'),
                        'SWIR': image.select('B5')
                    }).float()).rename('NDBI')});

print(ndbi)

//IBI: Index-based Built-up Index
var ibi = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.select().addBands(image.expression(
                        '(NIR / (NIR + RED)) + (GREEN / (GREEN + SWIR))', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B4'),
                        'RED': image.select('B3'),
                        'GREEN': image.select('B2'),
                        'SWIR': image.select('B5')
                    }).float()).rename('IBI')});

print(ibi)
  
var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};


//Map.addLayer(rgb,visParams, 'R5G6B4');
Map.addLayer(ndbi.median(), colorizedVis, 'NDBI');
Map.addLayer(savi.median(),colorizedVis, 'SAVI');
Map.addLayer(ibi.median(),colorizedVis, 'IBI');


// Export a cloud-optimized GeoTIFF.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: savi,
  description: 'SAVI_00-03', 
  folder: 'GEE2',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  region: aoi,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
``
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `.select()` is wrong. The code you have:

```
var savi = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.select().addBands(image.expression(
                        '1.5 * (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + 5000)', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B4'),
                        'RED': image.select('B3')
                    }).float()).rename('SAVI')});
```

`.select()` function has these arguments:

> #### Arguments:
>
> **this:imagecollection (ImageCollection):**
>
> The ImageCollection instance.
>
> **selectors (List):**
>
> A list of names, regexes or numeric indices specifying the bands to
> select.

So, the use is `image.select(['B3','B4'])` for example.

Also, addBands isn't necessary here and requires another image and the bands to add. In the same way, `.expression` returns a single image. If you want to add this result to the original image with `.addBands` use something like this:

```
var savi = dataset.map(function(image) {
  var savi = image.expression('1.5 * (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + 5000)', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B4'),
                        'RED': image.select('B3')
                    }).rename('SAVI')
  return image.addBands(savi)
});
```

The result will be the original image + `'SAVI'` band.

If you want to store in different objects:

```
var savi = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.expression('1.5 * (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + 5000)', {
                        'NIR': image.select('B4'),
                        'RED': image.select('B3')
                    }).rename('SAVI')});
```